# How to skip a test and not fail it

Tags: java, selenium, junit

In the middle of the test, if the condition of the test is not satisfied, how can I skip the test without failing it.

I try to throw an exception and it is marked as failed.

Comment: `@Ignore` on the test method or class

Comment: @Ignore over the method declaration

Comment: https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Assumptions-with-assume

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use the assume:

```
org.junit.Assume.assumeTrue(condition());
```

If this fails your test will be ignored.
I recommend doing this assume in your @Before method

Hope this helps

Comment: I use Assume all the time, but never in @Before. Why do you suggest that? Could you please explain.

Comment: The test will still be reported as failed, because: org.opentest4j.TestAbortedException - if the assumption is not true

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use some thing like

```
try {

 ///some process

try {
 ///your middle test 
}catch (excetion e){
}

}catch (excetion e){
}
```

If the middle test  is failed the rest will work